# what's the meaning of short scans?

Tags: database, apache-kudu

Recently,I'm learning something about Apache Kudu.
I have this words:*For workloads involving many short scans, where the overhead of contacting remote servers dominates, performance can be improved if all of the data for the scan is located in the same tablet.*
I don't understand the short scans.Can you give me some examples to help me to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two database calls - one of them fetches a single value from a database with a well-defined primary key. Another has to join fifty tables and run some computation on them. If you spent 1 minute on these calls, you might get 50 calls of the first, and only 2 of the second. The first option must make a connection to the database, which carries significant overhead. The second has much less overhead.

By loading this data on the tablet, you can avoid those network calls that might slow down the app.